# Declaring an outer class with & without public keyword

Tags: java, oop

whats the difference between declaring an outer class with and without public keyword in java. i know that an outer class cannot be private, so when we don't use public keyword, does the IDE or java compiler know by default that this must be a public class?

```
public class Main {
   // program code
}

class Main {
   // program code
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: A public class is accessible from outside the package that contains it.

Comment: i know how public, private and protected works, but i was just wondering  in case we don't specify any keyword before declaring a class. @leoderprofi thanks i just read that.

Comment: Syed - read the tutorial.  It answers your question.  Yes.  It really does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

classes when declared without any specified keyword is recognised as package-private, means the class can only be used inside the package.

Answer (score 2):

> whats the difference between declaring an outer class with and without
>   public keyword

It is a public class if `public` is specified and a `package-private` class if it is omitted.

> so when we don't use public keyword, does the IDE or java compiler
>   know by default that this must be a public class?

A class with no access modifier specified such as `class Main { }` is a package private class.
I don't see why any IDE would not respect this specification of the language to replace this modifier with the `public` access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Outer classes can only be declared public or package private, for usability. A private outer class won't be very usable. [More about nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: yep, what if you don't specify any keyword before declaring the class. would it be private, public, protected or package-private. thats what i'm asking